# Время на c# и на Android

Tags: android, c#, дата, datetime

в C# есть возможность передать время через массив байтов таким образом:

```
DateTime FromDate = DateTime.Now;
b = BitConverter.GetBytes(FromDate.ToBinary())
//и обратно
FromDate = DateTime.FromBinary(BitConverter.ToInt64(b, 0));
```

как сделать тоже самое на андроид?

```
Date FromDate = new Date();
byte[] bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(FromDate.getTime()).array();
```

оно возвращает во первых массив развёрнутый. а во вторых значения разные.

можно привести в нужный вид из андроида с помощью функции:

```
static DateTime JavaLongToCSharpLong(long javaLong)
{
    TimeSpan ss = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(javaLong);
    DateTime Jan1st1970 = 
        new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    DateTime ddd = Jan1st1970.Add(ss);
    DateTime final = ddd.ToUniversalTime();

    return final;
}
```

но мне нужно чтобы андроид код сразу выдавал значение, которое можно будет принять без этой функции

Comment: я попробовал добавить дату (1970, 1, 1); не сработало.. нужно именно правильно сохранить в андроид варианте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

решил так:

```
 ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(dt2.getTime().getTime()*10000+621355968000000000l).array();
```

т.е. добавил разницу во времени

(dt2.getTime().getTime()*10000 - это не очень точно, но для моей задачи достаточно)

Comment: dt2.getTime().getTime() - здесь dt2 это экземпляр класса Calendar именно по этому два раза написано ".getTime() " - сначала получаем класс Date а потом уже численное значение